# Paypal button Return Url target

Tags: paypal

I am embedding Paypal button into my app and, customizing it by following https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/button-js-builder/

The issue is, I want to close the popup window and refresh my main site with the Return URL, but actually the popup window is refreshed.

Question is how to close the popup window and refresh the main site.

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/ClosingWindow/

Comment: Hi Deep, Thank you. But I am asking log in only, not checkout. And there is no Cancel Url to set.

Comment: You need to close the popup window yourself before doing the post.